# Adding attention to seq2seq LSTM Model

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, time-series, lstm

I'm trying to make a time series prediction project for stock prediction that also displays feature weights (as in, what aspects of the data were most important - i.e. closing price, volume, technical indicators, fundamentals, etc.) and attention. More specifically, given a starting date, the model should predict the next 30 days of closing prices using the previous 120 days of data. Additionally, it should print out the feature weights as well as how much attention the model gave to the data of each of those previous 120 days in making its prediction.

I figured out the feature weights using LIME and sub-par but still workable results on historical data for stock price prediction, with around 10-15% rms error. I'm not too worried about the rmse error right now, because I anticipate better data and attention and better hyperparameter tuning will improve that significantly. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to add attention to the model, as well as how to print out the attention weights.

Here's my training script:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Dense, RepeatVector, TimeDistributed, Attention
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import json
import joblib
import sys
import os
from datetime import datetime



 # Create sequences for single ticker
def create_sequences(input_data, target_data, window_size, forecast_horizon):
    X, y = [], []
    for i in range(window_size, len(input_data) - forecast_horizon + 1):
        X.append(input_data[i-window_size:i])
        y.append(target_data[i:i+forecast_horizon])
    return np.array(X), np.array(y)
    

def train(ticker, forecast_horizon, window_size, epochs=25, batch_size=32, training_split = 0.9):

    # Load data for a single ticker
    f = open('../../data/processed/data.json')  
    data_json = json.load(f)
    ticker_data = data_json[ticker]['Time Series (Daily)']
    f.close()

    df = pd.DataFrame(ticker_data).T
    df = df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'Date'})
    
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
    df.sort_values(by='Date', inplace=True)
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

    numeric_features = df.drop(columns=['Date']).columns

    # Initialize scalers for the features and target
    scaler_features = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
    scaler_target = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))

    scaled_features = scaler_features.fit_transform(df[numeric_features])
    scaled_target = scaler_target.fit_transform(df[['close']])

    X, y = create_sequences(scaled_features, scaled_target, window_size, forecast_horizon)

    # Split data into training and test sets
    split = int(training_split * len(X))
    X_train, X_test = X[:split], X[split:]
    y_train, y_test = y[:split], y[split:]

    # Define the seq2seq model architecture


    #encoder
    encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(window_size, X.shape[2]))
    encoder = LSTM(50, return_state=True, dropout=0.2)
    encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder(encoder_inputs)
    encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

    #decoder
    decoder_inputs = RepeatVector(forecast_horizon)(encoder_outputs)
    decoder_lstm = LSTM(50, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.2)
    decoder_outputs = decoder_lstm(decoder_inputs, initial_state=encoder_states)

    #dense
    decoder_dense = TimeDistributed(Dense(1))
    decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)

    model = Model(encoder_inputs, decoder_outputs)

    # Compile the model
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

    # Train the model
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))

    # Save the model and scalers
    model.save(f'../bin/{ticker}/{forecast_horizon}f_{window_size}w_model.keras')
    joblib.dump(scaler_features, f'../bin/{ticker}/{forecast_horizon}f_{window_size}w_scaler_features.pkl')
    joblib.dump(scaler_target, f'../bin/{ticker}/{forecast_horizon}f_{window_size}w_scaler_target.pkl')
```

And the prediction script:

```
import joblib
from keras.models import load_model
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import json
import sys
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import os
from lime import lime_tabular
import concurrent.futures





# Create sequences for single ticker
def create_sequences(input_data, target_data, window_size, forecast_horizon):
    X, y = [], []
    for i in range(window_size, len(input_data) - forecast_horizon + 1):
        X.append(input_data[i-window_size:i])
        y.append(target_data[i:i+forecast_horizon])
    return np.array(X), np.array(y)


def load(ticker, window_size, forecast_horizon, root_path):
    
    model_path = os.path.join(root_path, f'models/bin/{ticker}/{forecast_horizon}f_{window_size}w_model.keras')
    feat_path = os.path.join(root_path, f'models/bin/{ticker}/{forecast_horizon}f_{window_size}w_scaler_features.pkl')
    target_path = os.path.join(root_path, f'models/bin/{ticker}/{forecast_horizon}f_{window_size}w_scaler_target.pkl')

    model = load_model(model_path)
    scaler_features = joblib.load(feat_path)
    scaler_target = joblib.load(target_path)

    return (model, scaler_features, scaler_target)


def calculate_rmspe(y_true, y_pred):
    # Ensure no zero denominators; add a small value, epsilon, to avoid division by zero errors.
    epsilon = 1e-10
    # Calculate percentage errors
    percentage_errors = ((y_true - y_pred) / (y_true + epsilon)) ** 2
    # Calculate mean of percentage errors
    mean_percentage_error = np.mean(percentage_errors)
    # Return RMSPE
    return np.sqrt(mean_percentage_error) * 100



def predict(ticker, window_size, forecast_horizon, start_date, cached_model, root_path):


    model, scaler_features, scaler_target = cached_model

    # Load data for a single ticker
    data_path = os.path.join(root_path, f'data/processed/data.json')
    f = open(data_path)  
    data_json = json.load(f)
    ticker_data = data_json[ticker]['Time Series (Daily)']  # Replace TICKER with your actual ticker
    f.close()

    df = pd.DataFrame(ticker_data).T
    df = df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'Date'})
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
    df.sort_values(by='Date', inplace=True)
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

    numeric_features = df.drop(columns=['Date']).columns

    scaled_features = scaler_features.fit_transform(df[numeric_features])
    scaled_target = scaler_target.fit_transform(df[['close']])


    dates_full = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])


    X, y = create_sequences(scaled_features, scaled_target, window_size, forecast_horizon)

    # Split data into training and test sets
    split = int(0.9 * len(X))
    X_train, X_test = X[:split], X[split:]
    y_train, y_test = y[:split], y[split:]

    if (type(start_date) == str):
        dt = pd.to_datetime(start_date)
    else:
        dt = start_date


    while(len(df.index[df['Date'] == dt].tolist()) == 0):
        dt = dt + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d')


    start_date= dt


    # Find the index of the start date
    start_idx = df.index[df['Date'] == pd.to_datetime(start_date)].tolist()[0]

    # Prepare the input sequence for the model
    input_sequence = scaled_features[start_idx - window_size:start_idx]
    input_sequence = input_sequence.reshape((1, window_size, -1))


    def lstm_predict_wrapper(model, data_2d):
        # The number of samples will be the first dimension of data_2d
        num_samples = data_2d.shape[0]

        # Reshape the data to 3D format (samples, timesteps, features)
        # The last timestep of each sample is used for prediction
        data_3d = np.zeros((num_samples, window_size, 26))
        data_3d[:, -1, :] = data_2d  # Set the last timestep
        predictions = model.predict(data_3d)

        return predictions[:, -1, 0]
    
    input_sequence_for_lime = input_sequence[0, -1, :].reshape(1, -1)



    explainer = lime_tabular.LimeTabularExplainer(
    training_data=X_train.reshape(-1, X_train.shape[2]), # Flatten the training data
    feature_names=numeric_features,
    mode='regression'
    )

    exp = explainer.explain_instance(
        input_sequence_for_lime[0], 
        lambda x: lstm_predict_wrapper(model, x),
        num_features=len(numeric_features)
    )

    feature_importance = {feature: weight for feature, weight in exp.as_list()}


    # Predict the next 30 days
    predicted_prices_scaled = model.predict(input_sequence)

    # Inverse transform the predicted scaled prices to the original price scale
    predicted_prices = scaler_target.inverse_transform(predicted_prices_scaled.reshape(-1, 1)).reshape(-1, forecast_horizon)
    predicted_prices=predicted_prices.flatten()


    actual_prices_scaled = scaled_target[start_idx:start_idx + forecast_horizon]
    actual_prices = scaler_target.inverse_transform(actual_prices_scaled)


    actual_prices_full_scaled = scaled_target
    actual_prices_full = scaler_target.inverse_transform(actual_prices_full_scaled)


    actual_prices=actual_prices.flatten()
    rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(actual_prices, predicted_prices))
    rmspe = calculate_rmspe(actual_prices, predicted_prices)

    dates_full = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
    forecast_dates = dates_full[start_idx:start_idx + forecast_horizon]


    return {
        'ticker': ticker,
        'window_size': window_size,
        'forecast_horizon': forecast_horizon,
        'start_date': start_date,
        'predicted_prices' : predicted_prices,
        'forecast_dates': forecast_dates,
        'dates_full' : dates_full,
        'actual_prices': actual_prices,
        'actual_prices_full': actual_prices_full,        
        'rmse': rmse,
        'rmspe' : rmspe,
        'feature_importance' : feature_importance
    }


# Visualize the results

def visualize(predictions):

    rmses = [p['rmse'] for p in predictions]
    rmspes = [p['rmspe'] for p in predictions]

    print(f'Average RMSE:', sum(rmses)/len(rmses))
    print(f'Average RMSPE:', sum(rmspes)/len(rmspes))

    


    print('\nAverage Feature Importance:')

    data = dict()
    for p in predictions:
        for f,w in p['feature_importance'].items():
            if f not in data.keys():
                data[f] = 0
            else:
                data[f] += float(w)
    
    for k,v in data.items():
        data[k] /= len(predictions)

    print(data)

    p0 = predictions[0]

    plt.figure(figsize=(15, 7))
    plt.plot(p0['dates_full'],p0['actual_prices_full'], label='Actual Prices', color='blue')
    plt.plot(p0['forecast_dates'],p0['predicted_prices'], label='Predicted Prices', color='red')
    for p in predictions:
        plt.plot(p['forecast_dates'],p['predicted_prices'], color='red')
    plt.title(f'Actual vs Predicted Stock Prices for the next {p["forecast_horizon"]} days')
    plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.ylabel('Price')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

I've been having trouble using the keras `Attention()` layer and understanding where it should go in this model's structure, and I'd also like to know how to eventually retrieve the attention weights and forward them in the `predictions` dict in the `predict()` output, like I did with the feature weights.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in NLP the attention techniques are theoretically logical when computing token-to-token "attention", and it has been successful both in seq2seq LSTMs and in transformers. The main reason why that works is primarily that the natural language (in any language) has a very limited combination both of alphabet and words. If you think about the alphabet Σ, and all posibilities Σ*, and the natural language Σ', it should be very clear that the case is |Σ'| << |Σ*| (which is infinite in theory though). Anyway, my point is token-to-token either being subword or word level dependencies can be captured easily because there are some repeated patterns and contexts.

In modeling continuous domain (e.g. price prediction), it inherently becomes a much more difficult problem, because the initial space is not discrete, continuous, and you basically do not have some kind of **finite** vocabulary, but instead you have a domain in real numbers or natural numbers. Nevertheless, I cannot directly say whether adding attention mechanism would work or not, you can try it out.

I have to say that I do not know if attention mechanism is applied in these kind of tasks for deep learning models. However, my initial suggestion would be that you first get the grasp of the attention mechanism and what it actually does, then you can add attention mechanism and train your model if you think it fits your problem. In LSTMs there is a prominent attention mechanism which is an additive attention mechanism called Bahdanau Attention (named after the first author of the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.0473)). There is a good [quick read](https://machinelearningmastery.com/the-bahdanau-attention-mechanism/), if you don't want to read the paper, but I strongly suggest that you read. Few reseources in pytorch

- [Bahdanau-Attention-in-Pytorch](https://github.com/lukysummer/Bahdanau-Attention-in-Pytorch)
- [NLP From Scratch: Translation with a Sequence to Sequence Network and Attention](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/seq2seq_translation_tutorial.html)

I'm sure there are TF/keras implementations out there. Finally let me say that Bahdanau Attention is just a type of attention mechanisms, there are many more attention types.